# How to define a tile structure for a 2D tile based game?

Tags: c++, tiles

I'm making a 2d tile based game, and I've tried to keep my tile structure small by using bit fields and bytes for the values in the tile structure:

```
struct Tile
{
    // 3 bytes (24 bits)
BYTE i : 8; // Texture index (0-255)
BYTE p : 1; // Passable (0-1)
BYTE x : 7; // Texture x (0-127)
BYTE y : 7; // Texture y (0-127)
BYTE v : 1; // Visible (0-1)
};
```

so if i have a 2d array of 1024x1024 tiles, then its only around 3mb in memory and when i save/load from hd.

But now I need animated tiles, so I need extra data like,

```
struct Tile
{
#define TILE_NORMAL     0
#define TILE_ANIMATED   1
    BYTE tile_type;

    // 3 bytes (24 bits)
    BYTE i : 8; // Texture index (0-255)
BYTE p : 1; // Passable (0-1)
BYTE x : 7; // Texture x (0-127)
BYTE y : 7; // Texture y (0-127)
BYTE v : 1; // Visible (0-1)

    // For animated tiles
    BYTE frame;
    BYTE maxFrame;
    float frameTime;
};
```

On each of the tiles, and since the 2D array is defines like:

Tile tiles[x][y];

Each tile would be around 10 bytes, even though a very small proportion of the tiles are animated.

I was thinking to store a 2D array of pointers, and then each points to either a normal tile or a animated one, but that would mean every pointer is 4 bytes, and points to atleast 4-10 bytes.

Comment: Are you programming for a game boy with 8MB memory? Are you sure this is a bottleneck.

Comment: how did gameboy do it then, i remember pokemon had massive maps with some tiles static and others animated

Comment: @Kaije: they used to load only a subset at a time, enough to fill a few screens. Also, there were only a few kinds of tiles (one byte per tile probably), and maps were not that large. IIRC, the maps from Zelda Link's Awakening were something like 512x512, and the whole ROM fitted into a few hundreds kilobytes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save memory, don't store the animation data in the tiles themselves. Instead, you could define a separate struct in your game program, such as:

```
struct AnimationSequence
{
    BYTE first;
    BYTE current;
    BYTE frames[];
    float frametime;
}
```

Then you could define an array of a couple of these which represent each type of tile that animates, and how it animates. Then, in your animation timer, cycle through this array, check it against the tiles on the screen, and redraw them as needed.

Another thing you might want to consider, to save more memory, is *not* storing X/Y coordinate values in the tile data. I'm assuming your X/Y bytes represent the position the tile is drawn on the screen, or something similar. You could try attaching the coordinate values to the view window of the game in their own array, rather than to the tiles themselves, so that you would only have one view window worth of tiles to serve as a lookup list for when you are drawing them to the screen, rather than a whole map's worth.

Comment: The x and y stored in the tile, is the texture postion, I have a big sprite sheet which is 1024x1024 pixels, with 32x32 tile images on, to get the texture "rectangle" i do like: rect.left = (tile.x * TILE_WIDTH), rect.right = rect.left + TILE_WIDTH. And then draw it to the screen. The actual tiles are positioned by two for loops, incrementing the x and y by 32.

Comment: But you already have tile.index, which tells you the same thing, so X and Y are redundant. (tile.index % 32) * 32 will give you the X pixel position of the tile from the sprite sheet, math.floor(tile.index / 32) * 32  will give you the Y pixel position. You can calculate these positions on the fly when drawing (which might make processing a little slower), or you could calculate them all once and save them in a lookup list array. (Assuming tile.index represents a particular rectangle or object from your sprite sheet; though I don't see how it's possible with a max of 255, so I could be wrong.)

Comment: tile index is the index of the texture, i did say i have a 1024x1024 texture, but theres actually lots of them in an array, so the texture id on each tile is which texture they use to render, like Draw(textures[tile.i], &rect);

Answer (score -1):

Could you make the struct a union?  For example (and please pardon any syntax errors, I don't remember the exact syntax):

```
struct Tile
{
#define TILE_NORMAL     0
#define TILE_ANIMATED   1
    BYTE tile_type;

    // 3 bytes (24 bits)
    BYTE i : 8; // Texture index (0-255)
    BYTE p : 1; // Passable (0-1)
    BYTE v : 1; // Visible (0-1)
    BYTE x : 7; // Texture x (0-127)
    BYTE y : 7; // Texture y (0-127)

    union
    {
        struct AnimatedTileData
        {
            // For animated tiles
            BYTE frame;
            BYTE maxFrame;
            float frameTime;
        };

        struct NoData
        {
        };
    };
};
```

So, in this way, you have one extra byte to say whether it is animated or not.  If it is not animated, then 'NoData' will be used, added no overhead.  If the tile is animated, then the 6 overhead bytes are added for animation related data.

Comment: But the union will always consume memory for the largest data type, being it used or not. No saving with this.

Comment: Bah! You are right. I didn't realize that unions worked that way. Sorry.